# gcloud run deploy promote 100% traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I'm deploying my app in the following way:

```
gcloud run deploy ${{ secrets.SERVICE_NAME }} \
  --source $(pwd) \
  --region us-central1 \
  --allow-unauthenticated \
  --platform managed
```

And it works fine.

However, I manually changed my service to serve the traffic 100%; now, every time that I deploy, the latest deployment doesn't get promoted, and it still keeps serving the old one.

To revert this behavior, what do I do, pass a flag or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try setting this:

`gcloud run services update-traffic SERVICE --to-latest`

Take a look at [Send all traffic to the latest revision](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration#send-to-latest)

Comment: It worked, however, it requires a region, in my case `--region us-central1`